# How to make a custom package available for raspberry pi 2?

Tags: raspbian, pi-2, packages

Is there is some provision like ppa(launchpad.net) for raspberry pi 2?
I want to make my custom projects available for raspberry pi 2. So that other raspberry pi 2 can directly install packages using package manager.

Comment: You can still use launchpad/ppa. It's all just apt and dpkg anyway. The only real issue if making a proper .deb package. If you can do that, the rest is automatic.

Comment: @JohnKeates I am not getting any option in launchpad.net to make my package available for raspberry pi 2.

Comment: That's because that's not how it works. You need to add a line to sources.list pointing to your repo